# getValue() cplex C++

Tags: c++, cplex, getvalue

Actually, I'm a beginner on using cplex on C++.
I try to stock the values of a variable (IloIntVarArray) after solving the MIP on a vector that I've put as an argument of the function by getValue(), but it doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: How doesn’t it work? What is the return value of the solve method and of getCplexStatus? Please show us a small reproducible piece of code.

Comment: Like Ryan said, we need to know more details about what exactly you are doing. If you say "vector", do you mean a `std::vector`? That won't work. The `getValue()` function takes a *single* variable as argument. In order to query multiple variables in one shot, use function `getValues()`. This takes as argument either an `IloNumVarArray` or an `IloIntVarArray` (not a `std::vector`). Please also see the many examples that ship with CPLEX. They illustrate how to query values from an `IloCplex` instance after calling `solve()`. Also note that a solution is only available if `solve()` returned true

Comment: I've fixed the problems . Thank you for your answers !

Comment: @holdxx, could you please add an answer to your own question and tell what was the problem or close the question? Otherwise the question will always show as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example

```
IloNumArray values(getEnv());
getValues(values, _x);
for (int i = 0; i < _graph->GetArcCount(); i++)
{
    ClassOfArcs* arc = _graph->GetArc(i);
    arc->value = (double)values[arc->index];
}
values.clear();
```

Where x is an IloNumVarArray holding the value of variable x_ij (going from customer i to j). In the example, I wish to store the values of x in an std::vector _x.

Don't forget to do a value.end() when you finish passing all other variables in your model to avoid memory leaks.